# Read few parquet files at the same time in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I can read few json-files at the same time using * (star):

```
sqlContext.jsonFile('/path/to/dir/*.json')
```

Is there any way to do the same thing for parquet? Star doesn't works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3928) on the spark jira. It is supported from 1.4 onwards.

Without upgrading to 1.4, you could either point at the top level directory:

```
sqlContext.parquetFile('/path/to/dir/')
```

which will load all files in the directory. Alternatively, you could use the HDFS API to find the files you want, and pass them to parquetFile (it accepts varargs).

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'parquetFile'
`

Answer (score 31):

FYI, you can also:

- read subset of parquet files using the wildcard symbol * `sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/dir/part_*.gz")`
- read multiple parquet files by explicitly specifying them `sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/dir/part_1.gz", "/path/to/dir/part_2.gz")`

Comment: In addition you can also use a hadoop glob pattern or take advantage of the spark partitioning schema, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712465/179014 .

Answer (score 25):

```
InputPath = [hdfs_path + "parquets/date=18-07-23/hour=2*/*.parquet",
             hdfs_path + "parquets/date=18-07-24/hour=0*/*.parquet"]

df = spark.read.parquet(*InputPath)
```

Comment: im my case first i filter the files in s3 and then give the list to read.parquet() thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For Read: Give the file's path and '*'

Example

```
pqtDF=sqlContext.read.parquet("Path_*.parquet")
```